# Formatting any date into MM/dd/yyyy

Tags: regex, vb.net, visual-studio, reporting-services

Hi I'm currently working on some SSRS reports and the data I am getting comes in quite a range. I'm getting dates in forms of:
6/18/2010 6:00:00 AM,
6/18/2010,
2010/6/18

I was hoping to be able to come up with a formatting code to use for the row so that it would convert any of these into the MM/dd/yyyy format and anything else just leave untouched. Unfortunately the scope of my VB skills do not compliment my objective. I was hoping someone might be able to help me with this. I was thinking something along the lines of iif(me.Value=####/##/####@##:##:##@@&, MM/dd/yyyy, nothing) but that doesn't seem to work.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: =iif(isDate(me.Value), "MM/dd/yy", nothing) works for everything except something like 2010/06/18.

Comment: Can you be sure that months and days are always in order mm/dd? Or could there be some instances of dd/mm around, too? Can there be two-digit years?

Comment: Recommendation: try to teach your users ISO8601 date format.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that me.Value is always going to be a date, just in different formats you can code an expression like

```
=DateTime.Parse(Fields!me.Value).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

If the data being pulled back may or may not be a date, then your best bet is to create a code block something like

```
Public Function FormatDate(Value as String) As String
    Dim NewDate as DateTime

    If (DateTime.TryParse(Value, NewDate)) Then
        FormatDate = NewDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
    Else
        FormatDate = ""
    End If
End Function
```

And then call this code block in your expresssion like

```
=Code.FormatDate(Fields!me.Value)
```

The DateTime.Parse function can figure out a lot of different formats of dates.  The only issue is that depending on the culture .Net is running under, a date like 1/2/2012 can be interpreted as January 2, 2012 or February 1, 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `String.Format("{0}", my_formatting)`

http://idunno.org/archive/2004/14/01/122.aspx

Comment: to do this in C language - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/strftime/

Comment: Is he asking for "C" language? It looks like he's looking for VB (as per the topic tags)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can take a look at the `Date.Parse` method. Some examples are available [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/VB/0100__Date-Time/ParseDate.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the input but this doesn't seem to help me

Answer (score 0):

```
\b(?<year>\d{4})/(?<month>\d{1,2})/(?<day>\d{1,2})\b|\b(?<month>\d{1,2})/(?<day>\d{1,2})/(?<year>\d{4})\b
```

will extract year, month and day from your string. It expects a four-digit year, accepts only slashes as separators, and expects months always before days.

It doesn't do any validation (checking for valid dates), but this is not something regexes are very good at - this should be done programmatically if it's at all necessary.

So in Visual Basic, this should look like

```
Dim RegexObj As New Regex("\b(?<year>\d{4})/(?<month>\d{1,2})/(?<day>\d{1,2})\b|\b(?<month>\d{1,2})/(?<day>\d{1,2})/(?<year>\d{4})\b")
year = RegexObj.Match(SubjectString).Groups("year").Value
month = RegexObj.Match(SubjectString).Groups("month").Value
day = RegexObj.Match(SubjectString).Groups("day").Value
```